# Date difference works in Firefox and IE but return NaN in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

I'm using that :

```
   function DateDiff(date1, date2) {

        var datediff = date2.getTime()- date1.getTime(); 
        return (datediff); 
    }
    $(document).on('dp.change', '#EndDate', function (e) {
            var StartDate= new Date($('#StartDate').val());
            var EndDate= new Date($('#EndDate').val());

            alert(DateDiff(EndDate, StartDate));

             ...
```

It doesnt work and returns NaN in Chrome (actually I'm trying to change days on DateTimePicker and it works until 12th days but it returns NaN after 12th days).

But it works in Firefox or IE.

Comment: are you sure that this doesn't work in chrome? what do $('#StartDate').val()  and $('#EndDate').val() return?

Comment: For the 10,000th time, do not use the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they do the same thing) to parse strings, it's largely implementation dependent. Write a 2 line function to parse it manually (or use a library, but you will spend more time learning the library than writing the function).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `momentjs` if your input is 'DD/MM/YYYY'

Comment: It didn't work . I don't understand why it works in Firefox or IE and why not in Chrome

Comment: Show, please, format of value in input with id `StartDate` and `EndDate`?

Comment: *has to be number* not true.

Comment: use `momentjs` to do what you need, because of your format is not standart for Date constructor

Comment: ah okay I got what's the problem. I looked again and It's showing May instead of March because of format .

Comment: Saying "use a library" is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings, always manually parse them (a library can help but is usually not necessary). E.g to parse a string in d/m/y format and validate the date, consider:

```
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
```